# TypeError: Discord.UserManager.resolve is not a function Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot using slash commands and I'm making a ban command. I am using `Discord.UserManager.resolve()` to resolve a Discord user's ID or a GuildMember to a User object. However, when I try to use `Discord.UserManager.resolve()` it returns the error `TypeError: Discord.UserManager.resolve is not a function`.

Note: The bot uses command files stored in a separate folder. Here is the `module.exports`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Ban a person from the guild.',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'byid',
            description: 'Ban a member using their unique UserId, whether they are in the guild or not.',
            type: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    required: true,
                    description: 'The user\'s ID.',
                    type: 'STRING'
                },
                {
                    name: 'reason',
                    required: false,
                    description: 'The reason why you banned the user.',
                    type: 'STRING'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'bymention',
            description: 'Ban a user by @mentioning them.',
            type: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'member',
                    required: true,
                    description: 'The member to ban.',
                    type: 'USER'
                },
                {
                    name: 'reason',
                    required: false,
                    description: 'The reason why you banned the user.',
                    type: 'STRING'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    permissions: [
        {
          id: '784539540101660712',
          type: 1,
          permission: true,
        }
      ],
    defaultPermission: false,
    async execute(interaction, bot) {
        console.log(interaction.options)
        let member = 0
        try {
            // member
            member = interaction.options.get('member').member
        } catch (error) {
            // id
            member = interaction.options.get('id').value
        }
        if (!bot.guilds.cache.get('784526382788771870').me.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS, true)) {
            interaction.reply('I don\'t have permission to ban members! Please contact an administrator or add the `BAN MEMBERS` permission on my role. ')
            return
        }
        member = Discord.UserManager.resolve(member)
        if (member.id === 856263292872163348) {
            interaction.reply('You want to ban me after all my hard work? What a disgrace.')
            return
        }
        if (member.bannable === true || interaction.guild.members.fetch(member)) {
            interaction.guild.members.ban(member, { reason: reasonval })
            interaction.reply(`Success! ${member.tag} was banned for ${reasonval}.`)
        } else interaction.reply('I can\'t ban this user. Make sure I have the BAN MEMBERS or ADMINISTRATOR permission, and my highest role is higher than the user\'s highest role.')
        
}
```

Comment: Use [`interaction.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=member).

Comment: The member that is being banned is inputted as either a GuildMember (using interaction.options.get('member').member) or a UserId, which I need to resolve into a User either way.

Comment: Quick tip: `if (member.id === 856263292872163348)` must be changed! Member ids are strings, and the number won’t actually be the number you see there due to JavaScript having a max safe number. Please make it a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UserManager.resolve](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=resolve) is not a static function (it doesn’t get called on the class itself). You probably meant to call it on [Client.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) instead.

```js
member = bot.users.resolve(member)
//I assume bot is your client
```